# Get paragraph id in field template

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I have a paragraph template where I print a field, for instance :

```
{{ content.field_products }}
```

In this template, I can get the paragraph id with :

```
paragraph.id()
```

I need to pass this paragraph id in the field template. What is the cleaner and simple way to do this ?
I found a solution like this :

```
{{ content.field_products|merge({666:paragraph.id()}) }}
```

and then I get the value in field template like this :

```
{% set paragraphId = items[items|length-1].content %}
```

But this is dirty and generate a warning "Message d'erreurUser error: "4" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 99 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php)." that I can understand giving that it's a dirty hack and drupal try to render my "666" array.

I'm probably gonna get the array with "666" key I added in a preprocess_field(), create a new variable for the field template et delete this diabolic hack from $variables to remove the warning due to a tentative to render this fake array, but I guess there is a better way to do ? I want simply to pass a variable from a template to its child...

thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clean solution is template preprocessing: In `yourtheme.theme` create something like

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $parentEntity = $element['#object'];
  //might be useful for if-clause: $variables['field_name'] and $variables['field_type']
  if ($parentEntity && $parentEntity->getEntityTypeId() == 'paragraph' ) {
    //whatever logic you need goes here, e.g. something like
    //$variables['attributes']['data-from-parent-paragraph'] = $parentEntity->getYourStuff();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, in preprocess this is easier to find, but once you know where to look you can do this in TWIG as well: `{{ element['#object'].id }}`